# Where should I put stress in these sentences?

Tags: pronunciation, stress, intonation

I am studying intonation and stress in English, and would like advice on where to put stress on these sentences.

1. "How do you do?"
   Does it sound like this? HOW do you DO?
2. Where should I put stress on this sentence:
   "Did you say you were holding a party?" to get an answer like this one:
   "No, I definitely did not."
   Should I put it on "Did" or "say"? Or somewhere else?
3. "Is he going to take that job?"
   Should I emphasize "IS" to get an answer: "No, he changed his mind."

Comment: (1) "How do you do" (I've even missed out the question mark) is almost always equivalent to "Hello". Typically, there might be a slight stress on 'How', or the final 'do', or no real stress at all. It's not a true sentence, where stress would have importance, so it is sensible to use the unmarked version. Sometimes, to convey delight at finally meeting a boyhood hero say, real stress on both 'How' and the final 'do', and a sing-song intonation, might be used. (2) Slight stress on PARty. (3) 'TAKE' if the previous sentence wasn't about 'him' re the job; IS if it was.

Comment: Just for my own benefit: is "to hold a party" a correct English expression?

Comment: @painfulenglish Yes, you can *hold* a party, but most people would say they *give*, *have*, *throw*, *put on*, *set up*, or *host* one, or more formally, *organize* or *arrange* one.

Answer (score 1):

Emphasis always depends on context, so clean answers are not possible without more of the dialog.

1) If you are beginning a conversation, it would be "*How* do you *do*?" with more emphasis on "do" than on "how". If you are reciprocating the same statement from someone else, emphasis would be on "you".

2) This one depends on what you thought you had heard before. If you KNOW that you heard this person say they were holding some event, but you weren’t sure it was a party, you would emphasize "party". If you heard that a party was to be held but you couldn’t make out who had mentioned it, you would emphasize "you".

3) Any of the words in this sentence could realistically be emphasized based on context. It looks like you want the case in which "he" was previously offered a job, and it had been discussed between these two people before. In that case, I would emphasize "job".

There are myriad reasons why one might emphasize different words within any of these examples, so this just covers the most routine cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface that I'm not highly experienced at this, so I tried explaining my reasoning as best I could. If there are any remarks on my approach being incorrect or not clear, I do apologize and hope to use this as a learning opportunity myself.

> "How do **you** do?"

That seems to sound more clean to me. Since we are asking how *they* are doing, we want to emphasize that we want *their* feelings. I want to include the 'how' as well, but it feels like you'd need 'do' also, otherwise your question would be: "**How** do **you** do?" This sounds like you are in a confused/amazement state of mind.

> "**Did** you **say** you were holding a party?"

Your core of that sentence is wanting to know if they *did* indeed *say* that. In this example in particular, the scenario at hand shouldn't be questionable on if there is a party held, but rather if that is something that they said or not. If you had 'did' only, it sounds like you want to know if there is a party. If you had 'say' only, you would be questioning the method of how this party was announced.

> "Is **he** going to take that job?"

I'm a little uneasy on this one. If you emphasize 'he', you are wanting to know if that specific person is the one going to take your job. However, it feels like if you want to know if you're still going to have a job, then 'is' would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stresses would be as follows: "*How* do you *do*?", "Did you *say* you were *hold* ing a *par* ty?", and "Is he *go* ing to *take* that *job*?" Putting a stress on "Is" in the third example would assume an answer like "Well, of *course* he's going to take the job!"